# Is there any institutions monitoring the scientific instruments performance?

Tags: data-request

In the last years, I've collected a lot of data from the datasheet of instruments used in surface metrology. That is useful for benchmarking the instruments we are developing. But I find strange that performances of instruments so important for the society are not monitored and made available from some institutions. And actually, the specs may be inaccurate. So my data are potentially biased by the adoption of different parameters and their calculation...

Am I missing something? Is there any register of the specs of the scientific instrument?

Comment: Check out nist.gov -- this is sort of their entire job.